# Obtener datos de 3 tablas SQL Server

Tags: sql

tengo poco comenzando a aprender SQL server y no puedo resolver un problema. Me pidieron resolver el siguiente problema: 
obtener la descripcion del departamento, clase, familia de las tablas cat_departamentos, cat_clases, cat_familias

La Tabla cat_familias contiene 1597 filas, y columnas: numdepto, numclase y descfamilia.

Tabla Cat_clases 219 filas, y columnas: numdepto, numclase, desclase

Tabla cat_departamentos  8 filas
columnas: numdepto, descdepto

Tengo que mostrar los datos mencionados en el problema y mi solucion es esta:

```
select descdepto, descclase, descfamilia from cat_familias 
inner join cat_clases on cat_familias.numdepto = cat_clases.numdepto
inner join cat_departamentos on cat_familias.numdepto = cat_departamentos.numdepto
```

la cual me trae 51366 filas como resultado . Pero la persona que me dejó el problema me menciona que me debe traer solo 1597 filas como resultado, pero no comprendo que tengo mal ya que no tengo mucho conocimiento de SQL. Pensé que mi solución era la correcta, supongo que tengo algun error en el inner join ya que no logro comprenderlo correctamente aun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exacto!! te debe traer solo 1597 filas.

Aunque a tu pregunta le falta un detalle importantisimo, cuales son las relaciones entre las tablas, esta se pueden "suponer" por los campos de las mismas...

Ahora fijate algo:

> La Tabla cat_familias contiene 1597 filas, y columnas: numdepto,
>   numclase y descfamilia.

esa tabla tiene 3 campos y describre a las categorias de familia.

> Tabla Cat_clases 219 filas, y columnas: numdepto, numclase, desclase

Esta tabla, tambien tiene 3 campos.. y describe a las categorias de clases.. Pero que casualidad, comparten 2 campos con la anterior! o sea, que la clave de esta y de la anterior son esos dos campos, juntos ;)

Y ahi es donde esta tu problema. Tu query esta bien, pero le falta un campo en la condicion de join.

```
select descdepto, descclase, descfamilia from cat_familias 
inner join cat_clases on cat_familias.numdepto = cat_clases.numdepto 
    and cat_familias.numclase= cat_clases.numclase
inner join cat_departamentos on cat_familias.numdepto = cat_departamentos.numdepto
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! funciona muy bien ahora